# Stable and fast configuration of Web Server to run Rails like apache + php on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, webserver

I'm looking for a good configuration of rails + a webserver. Actually I'm using webrick which has some problems (on 2 different machines): First, it crashes after XXX time (and it's not my application, it happens randomly on a brand new app). Second, it doesn't handle multiple requests, and my app uses a lot of small ajax calls making the website testing really slow for being on a local server with so small pages.

I thought I could install Rails + Apache but reading around I think it's not possible. What's the fastest configuration (that supports multi threaded requests) as a webserver to use with Rails?

I'm using wamp to handle my apache webserver, php, mysql and so on (yea I'm not an expert, but I can handle with configuration files). I would like to use rails through that apache if possible, I read I should use however apache + mongrel (can I handle multiple requests in this way?).

I'm ok with other configurations too, I just need someone to point me in the right direction and possibly on a tutorial.

**So requirements are:**

- Handle parallel requests (I have a lot of small requests)
- Stable (webrick crashes quite often)

Thanks a lot

**Edit 1:**

For those who like me uses virtual hosts, here is what I wrote:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@federtrek.org.localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/manage_federtrek_org"
    ServerName federtrek.org.localhost
    ServerAlias manage.federtrek.org.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/manage.federtrek.org-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/manage.federtrek.org-access.log" common
    ProxyPass / http://manage.federtrek.org.localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://manage.federtrek.org.localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Where port 3000 is mongrel server and 8080 is apache port.
Follow the pdf document linked in the answer to make it works.

Comment: I don't get why the question should be closed, I'm asking for a software stable configuration which should be fast (webrick could be considered slow objectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webrick is not appropriate for a production environment; it should only be used for local development.

You're deploying Rails on Windows? Never heard of that being done before. If it were Linux or OS X and you insisted on using Apache, I would recommend Fusion Passenger (it's kind of like Ruby's mod_php). But I don't think they support windows.

I think your best bet is Mongrel...I *think* it runs under Windows. The idea is that you run one or more copies of your Rails app as Mongrel processes (services in Windows parlance?) You then setup Apache as a reverse-proxy to them, perhaps also doing some load balancing. While it's not actually multi-threading, it will have the same benefits. (In fact, most Rails deployments use this idea instead of true multi-threading.)

Should be lots of tutorials out there for this, on *nix at least. I think most of it will be the same for Windows. A quick Google search yielded this PDF specific to a Windows setup. http://www.napcsweb.com/howto/rails/deployment/RailsWithApacheAndMongrel.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, the answer seems exhaustive (I can only run Linux on a virtual machine, so I prefer developing on windows directly). I'll try in the next days and let you know the result.

Comment: I'm testing the pdf. The proxy configuration is not correct as explained (I'm trying it and it's not correctly working) but I'll read the documentation and fix it. By the way I think this is the way to go on Windows. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok after a lot of hours to find out how to make it works with virtual hosts, I found the solution and I can mark your answer as the correct one (see the edit to understand what I did).